# Could not able to delete collection rows in JPA while calling save()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have this below entity classes.

```
Parent Entity:
---------------
public class MLW implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "mlwId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String mlwId;
 
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="mlwId")
    private MLWJob mlwJob;

    private Date createdDate;
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;
}



public class MLWJob implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String mlwId;
    @Column(name = "Id")

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="mlwId")
    private List<MLWJobItem> items;
}

public class MLWJobItem implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String itemId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="itemId")
    private List<MLWJobItemExtension> mlwJobItemExtensions;
}


public class MLWJobItemExtension implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String extnId;
    @Id
    private String itemId;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}

Repository class:
------------------
public interface MLWRepository extends JpaRepository<MLW, String> {
}
```

When I try to call save method using above repository I am getting below exception. Could someone help me to understand and fix this issue? TIA

> could not delete collection rows:
> [com.cpc.wgln.entity.MLWJobItem.mlwJobItemExtensions#0105021001713441];
> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:
> could not delete collection rows:
> [com.cpc.wgln.entity.MLWJobItem.mlwJobItemExtensions#0105021001713441]

Comment: Please post the full stack trace (formatted as code please). Also show us the code you are executing, especially what you are doing with your entities.

Comment: Are you really still using JPA 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using JPA.

Comment: @JensSchauder I am trying to insert whenever I receive an XML from the API. Just extracted few more info from the log: could not delete collection rows: [com.cpc.wgln.entity.MLWJobItem.mlwJobItemExtensions#0105021001713441]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not delete collection rows: [com.cpc.wgln.entity.MLWJobItem.mlwJobItemExtensions#0105021001713441]


update Tablename set itemId=null where itemId=? and extnId=?

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 3 is out of range.